# What are the possible stealth ratings at the end of the game?

Tags: sir-you-are-being-hunted

Does anyone know about the stealth ranks you acquire at the end of the game? On my first playthrough I was not quite stealthy and I got something related with loudness, don't remember. Now on my second playthrough I got Upper Upper Class. I haven't been able to find anything conclusive. There's a barebones wiki [here](http://siryouarebeinghuntedwiki.com/wiki/Home), but I didn't find anything there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are thirteen total stealth ranks, of which "Upper Upper Class" is the fourth. Your rank is based on the number of times that you're noticed by the AI during the game (note that the game distinguishes between "being in line of sight" and "being in line of sight long enough to be noticed," and it's the latter being counted).

From worst to best, the ranks are:

1. Foreigner
2. Lower Working Class
3. Working Class
4. Upper Working Class
5. Lower Middle Class
6. Middle Class
7. Upper Middle Class
8. Lower Upper Class
9. Upper Class
10. Upper Upper Class
11. Posh
12. Toff
13. Royalty

Comment: Oh yeah I remember now, I got Foreigner the first time. Thanks!

Comment: Dang, I got lower middle class the 1st time, upper upper class the 2nd, ragequit the 3rd, then toff the 4th...  I wonder what one has to do for royalty.